# Trying to understand gmapping and playback some bag

Tags: navigation, odometry, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I have a bag with scanner data. I am not trying to build a map.
THe scanner is in /scan.
So I ran
rosparam set use_sim_time true
roscore

rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan 
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 100

Nothing seems to be published in /map.
In rviz, I see for map... transform:No transform from [] to [laser]
What am I missing?
From the doc, I can see base_link → odom is needed.. How?
Why is that needed? Is not the purpose of slam to determine just that? (the base_link relative to odom)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225385/trying-to-understand-gmapping-and-playback-some-bag/) by [SeekerOfRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/25750/seekerofros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to use gmapping, you have to generate an odometry estimate by integrating your encoder and/or inertial measurements, and publish the estimate as a TF transform from base_link --> odom.  See my answer on another question for more details about how particle filter SLAM algorithms like gmapping work:

http://answers.ros.org/question/227425/why-gmapping-package-requires-the-base_link-odom-tf/?answer=228259#post-id-228259

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2016-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0